# How can I play video on my website

Tags: .net, asp.net

I want to play video in my website, the video are located on server. I want to play video and I want to handle that dynamically.
I can set from control panel which video will be played. I have tried using youtubevideo control or video control or other but unable to get success.
Please suggest me player which can play all type of format and with no tooltip on it

```
<object data="images/player_flv_maxi.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="342" height="234" hspace="1" vspace="0" align="middle" id="Object1">
                                    <param name="movie" value="images/player_flv_maxi.swf" />
                                    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                                    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
                                    <param name="autoload" value="true" />
                                    <param name="FlashVars" value="flv=20051210-w50s_56K.flv&amp;width=345&amp;height=234&amp;autoplay=1&amp;autoload=1&amp;buffer=5&amp;buffermessage=&amp;playercolor=464646&amp;loadingcolor=999898&amp;buttoncolor=ffffff&amp;buttonovercolor=dddcdc&amp;slidercolor=ffffff&amp;sliderovercolor=dddcdc&amp;showvolume=1&amp;showfullscreen=1&amp;playeralpha=100&amp;title=59067126&amp;margin=0&amp;buffershowbg=0" />
                                    <embed src="images/player_flv_maxi.swf" width="342" height="234" hspace="1" vspace="0" align="middle" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" quality="high" menu="true" autoplay="true" autoload="true" flashvars="flv=20051210-w50s_56K.flv&amp;width=345&amp;height=234&amp;autoplay=1&amp;autoload=1&amp;buffer=5&amp;buffermessage=&amp;playercolor=464646&amp;loadingcolor=999898&amp;buttoncolor=ffffff&amp;buttonovercolor=dddcdc&amp;slidercolor=ffffff&amp;sliderovercolor=dddcdc&amp;showvolume=1&amp;showfullscreen=1&amp;playeralpha=100&amp;title=59067126&amp;margin=0&amp;buffershowbg=0" movie="images/player_flv_maxi.swf"></embed>
                                  </object>
```

Friends I m using this code but this is not working at all can anyone tell me whats the problem

Comment: It's not only the player that matters, it's what the client can handle as well in terms of Codex etc. Thats why flash is such a good option, but that requires conversion of the incomming videos to a format that flash can play.

Answer (score 1):

**1. solution:** Use HTML5 `<video>` tag. You can control it with javascript. The downside is that this solution is not widely supported.

**2. solution:** Use youtube and their API. It is hard to get done propperly, but once you do, it works nice. It is hosted elsewhere and don't use your server bandwith.

**3. solution:** Use JWplayer. Google it. It also provides Javascipt API, but you must host videos on your own server (unlike youtube), using own bandwith and you have to convert them to .flv before use.

If I were you, I'd go with 3. solution. But it is up to you.

Comment: friend html5  is working on local system but when I use it in server It is not playing my video

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it propperly. Have you set the path to the video correctly on the server? Browser doesn't differentiate between localy and remotely, so problem is somewhere else. Google for `HTML5 <video> tag` for more info on this.

Comment: Yes my friend I have done it properly 
If it works on local system that means I have implemented it properly

Comment: Link if possible? Generally, as I said browser does not make a difference between server and local. If it works locally, it should work on server.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Strobe media player](http://www.osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html).  It is based on the OSMF (Open Source Media Framework).

On the server side you can use [Red5](http://www.red5.org/), if you want to add streaming capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think FlowPlayer from http://flowplayer.org/ is a brilliant solution.